# using Collections.Sort and compare on an object sorted by date

Tags: android, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of objects called dbDatas by earliest date first

[please excuse the convoluted way I acquire the dates d1 and d2, it's just how my classes are set up]

I found a number of examples on sorting using Collections.sort, but I could not tell if they would sort earlier dates first in the list, or later in the list.  Question is, will d1.before(d2) giving a return value of -1 put the earlier date first?  This may seem straightforward, but I'm just not finding the answer.  Thank you.

```
   private List<dbData> sortDBDataByDate(List<dbData> dbDatas, final String columnDate) {
        Collections.sort(dbDatas,new Comparator<com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.dbData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(dbData lhs, dbData rhs) {
                Date d1 = Utility.getDateFromString("M d yyyy", lhs.getMappedColumnValue(columnDate));
                Date d2 = Utility.getDateFromString("M d yyyy", rhs.getMappedColumnValue(columnDate));
                if (d1.before(d2))
                    return -1;
                else if (d1.equals(d2))
                    return 0;
                else
                    return 1;
            }
        });

        return dbDatas;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Collections.sort sorts in ascending order. What "ascending" means is defined by your comparison method. Negative means lhs comes before rhs, 0 means equal, positive means lhs comes after rhs.

This is detailed in the Comparator docs and also apparent in testing.

By the way, you can also return d1.compareTo(d2), as Date has that implemented already.

Comment: I guess it looks as though I didn't do my homework.  Maybe I'm staring too hard or in the wrong place, but did not see it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: @EdwardBagby I agree it is not directly apparent. However the collections doc states natural ordering, and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html defines how compare relates to natural ordering. Combined they give the answer. "Natural ordering", by the way, is a phrase worth adding to your vocabulary, it is used often in these contexts. Still, when in doubt, test!

Comment: Well,  I'm a relative newbie to Java.  Only been doing it about a month, that's why I'm asking the question, because I don't have the subtleties down. As far as testing, I'm building several back-end classes, and cant really test until a certain point, so I'm trying to be careful as I go.  Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if d1 is before d2 then returning -1 is correct.  You could simplify the if/else if/else block to:

```
return d1.compareTo(d2);
```

assuming d1 and d2 are not null

Comment: Is that not bad form to assume the value is not null?  In my case I am probably only calling it after a loop that ensures none of the values are null, but the key word is "probably."

Comment: @EdwardBagby Your current code also assumes lhs/rhs/d1/d2 are not null. The real "bad form", actually, is not knowing if values can be null or not. You will benefit from defining [invariants](http://bit.ly/1AJntbW) / [preconditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) / [postconditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition) and sticking to them. You need to be able to *definitively* say "the input list contains no nulls" or "the input list may contain nulls" (note that the latter is significantly different than "I don't really know what's going on").

Comment: Yes, I would agree.  I'm familiar with these concepts.  Collections.sort and compare in java were completely new to me.  I cannot think of anything comparable I've used in Visual Studio.  Not saying it is not there, just hadn't used it. My assumption from @rick's comment was that somehow his code accepted nulls while mine did not.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear what your question is. Are you asking whether you should sort dates ascending? Then the answer of course depends on your application. Are you asking whether your code sorts dates ascendingly? Well, yes because if a date is "before" another you are designating it as being smaller. If your question is whether Collections sort is ascending? Then the answer is yes, which is well-documented.